# When do you use articles in front of collective nouns?

Tags: grammar, articles, definite-article, collective-nouns

Which of the below is correct?

> You are a member of staff at the taxi office.
>
> You are a member of  **the** staff at the taxi office.

Answer (score 1):

"Member of staff" is an idiomatic term. It means you are a member of *a* staff of workers.

Because it is an accepted term, you don't need to add an article before 'staff'. You already have the article 'a' in "I am *a* member of staff".

Comment: Is this a BrE thing? "member of staff" sounds very odd to my native AmE ears

Comment: @Kevin "Member of staff" is certainly a common expression in BrE.

Answer (score 1):

STAFF is a plural word to talk collectively about some individuals working for an organization. It has no singular. 
e.g., The staff are on strike. (NOT, 'A staff is . . . ' but you can say 'a staff of workers', 'a staff of 10' etc.)
Three staff, four staff, etc.

However, we can say "A member of staff".

You say "A MEMBER OF STAFF" or A STAFF MEMBER (phrase in British English) to mean a member belonging to a staff of workers'. You need not say 'a member of the staff'.

Comment: I don't think I've ever heard anyone say "a member of staff".  It's either "a staff member" or "a member of the staff". At least in AmE